# How to check whether Quartz job is running?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

i have a UI on which i displayed the list of job . each job has RUN NOW button when i press the button Job starts and each job run in a specific interval. 
Now i want to stop specific job but

```
scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
```

returns nothing , How can i get reference of existing job so that i can stop that.
my Job class

```
public class SecondJob implements InterruptableJob{

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("My second JOB ");
    try {
        System.out.println(" job starts ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
    System.out.println(" JOB STOPS");

}
```

}

My controller below methods run the job

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/runNow" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> runNow(@RequestParam("jobFileName") String jobFileName,
        @RequestParam("jobLocation") String jobLocation) {
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SecondJob.class).withIdentity(jobFileName, jobFileName).build();

    System.out.println(" runNow jobFileName   " + jobFileName);
    System.out.println("  runNow jobLocation   " + jobLocation);

    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobFileName, jobFileName);
    try {

        if (scheduler == null) {
            StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = (StdSchedulerFactory) servletContext
                    .getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
            scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        }
        scheduler.getContext().put("jobLocation", jobLocation);
        scheduler.addJob(job, true);
        scheduler.triggerJob(jobKey);
        //schedulerFactory.getScheduler().triggerJob(jobKey);

        List<JobExecutionContext> runningJobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

below method calls when i click on stop button

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/stopJob" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> stopJob(@RequestParam("jobFileName") String jobFileName,
        @RequestParam("jobLocation") String jobLocation) {
    //JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SecondJob.class).withIdentity(jobFileName, jobFileName).build();

    System.out.println(" stopJob jobFileName   " + jobFileName);
    System.out.println("  stopJob jobLocation   " + jobLocation);

    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobFileName, jobFileName);
    try {

        if (scheduler == null) {
            StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = (StdSchedulerFactory) servletContext
                    .getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
            scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        }
        List<JobExecutionContext> runningJobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

        scheduler.getContext().put("jobLocation", jobLocation);
        //scheduler.addJob(job, true);
        scheduler.interrupt(jobKey);
        //scheduler.triggerJob(jobKey);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Please let me know what i need to do to solve ?

Comment: If your job only run very short period of time, it would likely not return in your list.

Comment: it is running after every 1 min.

Comment: Running time interval is 1 minute but job execution time is appx 1 ms because it is only printing a line with text "job starts". Try setting a thread sleep of couple of minutes inside your job and check.

Comment: even i put more time it is not working ,

Comment: If you are running in cluster, this may not work bcz this method will return from the node where it is called and job meanwhile running in other node.

Comment: the application is deployed on single web server .